# Reactjs useEffect lose data that retrived from useSelector if i did browser refersh

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I found a mysterious issue in useEffect with redux,

I have this action that gets data from API name: fetchOrders()

so in **allOrder.js** page, I put the following code:

```
//dispatch action
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const initOrders = useCallback(() => dispatch(fetchOrders()), [dispatch]);

//selectors
const mapState = useSelector((state) => {
    return {
        orders: Object.values(state.orders),
        resturantInfo: state.resturant.branchDetails,
        async: state.async.loading,
    };
});


useEffect(() => {
    initOrders();
    console.log(mapState.orders);
}, [initOrders]); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

then:

```
return(JSX and show all data from mapState use selector)
```

the issue is if I tried doing a double browser refresh the data will appear in the return function but the inside use effect will give me an empty redux state, why!

**Once component mount**
[image]

**after I did a browser refresh**
[image]

Comment: The state of your application, such as a component's state or the redux store, is stored in memory by default. So once you navigate away or refresh the page it's cleared. If you want to preserve Redux state you need to store it in the browser storage. Use can use `redux-persist` for this: https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist

Comment: cause you miss the `mapState` in your `useEffect` deps

Comment: The log: `console.log(mapState.orders);` is logging a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/) you should log mapState outside of the effect. Check the redux dev tools to see if the correct actions are dispatched and if they change the state correctly.